# Is it possible to make a dynamic height for DataTables?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, datatable

Hi guys I have a question. I have a DataTable where I display my database data. Now not all my data are not the same length some are bigger and some are smaller. I know that I can make a fixed height with `dataRowHeight` but this also means that I have a lot of free space when I don't have such a long dataset to display. Is it possible to make `dataRowHeight` dynamic so that it always fits perfectly to each dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an approach like this would help you to achieve your goal? You could calculate the value for your dataRowHeight based on the number of elements in the list you use to populate your DataTable. LayoutBuilder gives you the max. available height.

```
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final rowHeight = (constraints.maxHeight - 40) / someList.length;
        return DataTable(
          dataRowHeight: rowHeight,
          headingRowHeight: 40,
          showCheckboxColumn: false,
          columns: const <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'FirstColumn',
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text(
                'SecondColumn',
              ),
            ),
          ],
          rows: someList.map<DataRow>((element) {
            return DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    element[0],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    element[1],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using Table widget to create Custom Table in Flutter

Yes, it is possible with **Table** Widget:

- When you use **DataTable** it tries to create a table with equally sized rows.
- While using **Table** It gives you the flexibility to resize the rows dynamically based on the size of that particular row(TableRow).

Similar to **DataTable** widget, **Table** widget uses **TableRow** for specifying the internal Rows as how DataTable Uses the **DataRow** widget

### Example Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
      children: [
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text('Column 1'),
            Text('Column 2'),
            Text('Column 3'),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text('Data 1'),
            Text('Data 2'),
            Text('Data 3'),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: [
            Text('Data 4'),
            Text('Data 5'),
            Text('Data 6'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

NOTE: you can use

```
  defaultColumnWidth: const IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
```

for making the column's width dynamic but this is an expensive method to use according to the documentation.